# Unable to increase Esri Map size

Tags: arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a basic ASP.net web app that loads an ESRI base map. The index page looks like this:

[image: HTML code]

The JavaScript code:

```
      function (Map, FeatureLayer, LabelLayer, InfoTemplate) {
          var map;
          var initMap = function () {
              map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                  basemap: "topo",
                  center: [-82.6389, 27.872461], // longitude, latitude
                  zoom: 10
              });

              map.on("load", initMapLayers);
          };

          var initMapLayers = function () {

              var popup = new InfoTemplate();
              popup.setTitle("<div style='max-width: 200px;'><b>NTA Median Household Income</b></div>");
              popup.setContent("Demographic Value Will Go here");
              var ntaFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer("some/MapServer/0", {
                  mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
                  infoTemplate: popup,
                  outFields: ["NTA", "FranNTA"],
                  visible: false,
                  id: "coveredNTAs"
              });

              var ntaLabelLayer = new LabelLayer({ id: "ntaLabels", mode: "dynamic" });
              var featureLabelRenderer;
              ntaLabelLayer.addFeatureLayer(ntaFeatureLayer, featureLabelRenderer, "{NTA}");
              ntaLabelLayer.styling = true;



              var whereClause = "FranNTA IN ('3261LI','3261SV','3261SW','3261LJ','3261LD','3261LF','3261SU')";
              ntaFeatureLayer.setDefinitionExpression(whereClause);
              map.addLayer(ntaFeatureLayer, 1);
              map.addLayer(ntaLabelLayer, 4);
              ntaFeatureLayer.show();
              ntaLabelLayer.show();
              ntaFeatureLayer.setOpacity(0.5);
          };


          return {
              initMap: initMap
          }
      }
  );
```

The map loads up just fine but its height is prefixed to 400px. 
[image: Map image]

Do i need a Custom CSS to fix this? Changing the styling in developer tools doesn't seem to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default height is 400px, so you will need custom CSS. In many of the examples, you will see CSS like this:

```
<style>
  html, body, #mapDiv {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I have added that to my html page but no use. Is it something to do in which order the files are loaded? My guess is that the esri.css is loading after the custom css which is why its overwriting it.

Comment: I even made sure that esri.css is loading before my custom css in Fiddler. I'm using bootstrap not sure if thats making any difference. Frustrating that something this trivial isnt working.

Comment: Bootstrap should be fine. Ensure you have <style> tags around your CSS rules. Ensure the CSS rules are applied before the map loads. For example, as you mentioned, you can't edit the CSS rules in Developer Tools after the map has loaded.

Comment: I was to able to fix the height with adding a custom class to the CSS and applying that class to the Map ID. Interestingly if i use the same css code in the html with style tags it didn't work.